# Object Displacement between frames using cross correlation in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, templates

I would like to estimate the displacement of on object ( This object is a curve along the image) and i want to know how much it moves using cross correlation between successive frames:

I have a problem to determine the right size of the template ,when i change the template size , it give different results , can you help me

```
   a = imread('001.jpg');
   a1 = imread('002.jpg');

  im1 =  imcrop(a,[500 400 200 100]); % Template 
  im2 =  imcrop(a1,[300 300 820 360]);

  c = normxcorr2(im1,im2);
  figure, surf(c), shading flat



  %offset found by correlation
 [max_c, imax] = max(abs(c(:)));
 [ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(c),imax(1));
 corr_offset = [(xpeak-size(im1,2))
           (ypeak-size(im1,1))];

  % relative offset of position of subimages
   rect_offset = [(rect_a1(1)-rect_a(1))
           (rect_a1(2)-rect_a(2))];

    % total offset
   offset = corr_offset + rect_offset;
    xoffset = offset(1);
   yoffset = offset(2);
```

Comment: have you tried checking what happens when you load the same image as `a` and `a1`?

Comment: You haven't defined `rect_a` and `rect_a1`. Do you mean that `rect_a=[500 400 200 100]` and `rect_a1=[300 300 820 360]`?

Comment: Try to replace your images a, a1 with the following: `a = zeros(700); a(450:490,550:590) = ones(41); a1 = zeros(1200);  a1(410:450,860:900) = ones(41);`. I did the replacement and your code seems to work fine. This probably means that the nature of your images is such that the displaced object isn't 100% clear to detect